# How do I print data from another table based on their relationship in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have these tables and columns.
Department:

- Id (PK)
- Name

Equipment:

- Id (PK)
- Name
- Amount
- Status
- DepartmentId (FK)

I want to output all the columns of Equipment + the DerpartmentName from the Department table in the same table based on their relationship. How do I model their relationship in the Model class? And also what code should I write in the EquipmentController class?

I have tried the following in the Model class:

```
public class Department
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Department Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Equipment> Equipments{ get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class Equipment
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Equipment Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Amount { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public Department Department { get; set; }


    }
```

As for the DepartmentController and View class and I'm not sure how to start.

Comment: First of all create a viewModel by the property you need to print from both table. Then in your controller, join the both table by using `Include`.

Comment: Have you tried the solution provided? Is there anything else I can assist you on this?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Based on your comment you can keep your `Equipment class` as :

```
public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
public Department Department { get; set; }
```

Instead of

```
    [ForeignKey("Department")]
    public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
```

> As for the DepartmentController and View class and I'm not sure how to
> start.

Well, let's assume we have `Department` and `Equipment` as following:

**Demo Department and Equipment:**

[image]

**Modify Your Equipment Class:**

To Display all of your equipment along with your department name you should modify your `Equipment Class` as following:

```
public class Equipment
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Equipment Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Amount { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Status { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Department")]
        public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var allEquipmentByDept = _context.Equipment.Include(dept => dept.Department).ToList();
            return View(allEquipmentByDept);
        }
```

**Note:** You can put this `controller action` either in `Department` or `Equipment controller` based on your preference.

**View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<DotNet6MVCWebApp.Models.Equipment>


<table class="table table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Equipment Id
            <th>Equipment Name
            <th>Amount
            <th>Status
            <th>Department
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Id</td>
                <td>@item.Name</td>
                <td>@item.Amount</td>
                <td>@item.Status</td>
                <td>@item.Department?.Name</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Note: In `IEnumerable<DotNet6MVCWebApp.Models.Equipment>` here `DotNet6MVCWebApp` your project name.

**Output:**

[image]

For further knowledge on entity framework join and [`how to load related entity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data) you check our [`official document here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data)

Comment: a little bit off topic question, I can't add a new record for department after including Equipments ICollection in the Model class. But I can do it if I directly add it using SSMS. Do you have any idea why? I'm passing `Department obj` as a parameter in my Add Action Method.

Comment: Oh I see you are using this way to insert operation as well, Alright, no worries you can keep your `Equipments` before, it will work as well. No need to modify.